# What is the Service (Class) equivalent of ZF2 in Laravel

Tags: php, zend-framework2, laravel-5

I am still learning Laravel 5. I have had experience with ZF2 in the past, I am trying to understand what is Service equivalent in Laravel5.

We can create the Service class and reuse the code as we want and break it down in modules, Can we do the same in Laravel 5 if yes, what is the best practice for this.

Thanks

Comment: I have looked at MiddleWare and ServiceProvider but not sure if they are the same ?? any suggestions would be good.

Comment: Yup Laravel also has a IoC container (closest analogue of `ServiceManager` in ZF2) and it has the ability to share the same instance of a service (if needed). You should look into service providers (analogue to service factory in ZF2) and how to register them. Injecting services can be done in many ways, depending where you do it and how much are you going to test.